# PHP regex phone validation not working

Tags: php, regex

my PHP validation regex not working and i don't understand why. My code returning: 'Failure'.
I checked my regex pattern and it is valid: https://regex101.com/r/2Is2L5/2

Phone value is: +7 (555) 555–55–55

```
if(preg_match('/^\+?\d{1,3}\s*\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-–•\s]?\d{2}[-–•\s]?\d{2}$/', $_GET['userPhone'])) {
    echo 'Success';
}
else{
    echo 'Failure';
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What is this character (`•`) ?

Comment: show `var_dump($_GET['userPhone']);`

Comment: •   <=    Is the alternate character, if you suddenly change design

Comment: var_dump is: string(22) "+7 (555) 555–55–55"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
$ cat a.php
<?php
if(preg_match('/^\+?\d{1,3}\s*\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-–•\s]?\d{2}[-–•\s]?\d{2}$/u', '+7 (555) 555–55–55')) {
    echo 'Success';
}
else{
    echo 'Failure';
}
?>

$ php a.php
Success
```

Notice the `/u` modifier at the end. According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> u (PCRE_UTF8) This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE
>   that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are
>   treated as UTF-8. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to
>   match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level
>   E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid
>   since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been
>   regarded as valid UTF-8.

Comment: Hey thank you! I just add "u" modifier at the end, and finally get Success!